# In ASP.NET, a POST/Redirect/GET sequence with AJAX hits the redirected-to action twice

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Inside a view, I have the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <input type="submit" id="savebtn" value="Save" onclick="saveLayout()"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveLayout() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Page/SaveFaces/',
            data: {
               /* layout data of the page, irrelevant */
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function () {                
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The above hits the following action, which simply redirects the user back to the URL they came from (it's also supposed to save the data, but I've removed that part for simplicity, as it doesn't affect the problem):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFaces(string items)
{
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Then, due to the redirect, we go back to this pretty standard model-fetching action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
{
    var page = db.Pages.Find(id);
    if (page == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return View(page);
}
```

The problem is that **this last action is called twice**.

I have tried removing the AJAX call and doing a normal POST operation and the problem goes away. However, the data I'm trying to send is obtainable only through the a jQuery script and I can't put them in a form. I'm constrained to work with the AJAX method.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the action from being hit twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it might be a bit specific to my scenario, I just found an acceptable solution. Since all the data is provided through jQuery, I removed the form completely and replaced the submit button with a simple link.

So, this goes away:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <input type="submit" id="savebtn" value="Save" />
}
```

And this is put in place instead:

```
<a onclick="saveLayout()" id="saveLink">Click to save.</a>
```

Now the `[HttpPost]` action is hit, the data is saved and the redirected-to action is also hit, once.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using `jQuery`. Can you try this instead? (Note you may have to bind the the `form` submit event rather than the input button, or both)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <input type="submit" id="savebtn" value="Save" >
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#savebtn").submit(function saveLayout(event) {
        // The magic that prevents post.
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Page/SaveFaces/',
            data: {
               /* layout data of the page, irrelevant */
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function () {                
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Also if you have access to form element, another way:

```
<form onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
```

Comment: Indeed I'm using jQuery. I've tried your approach but now the script doesn't run at all when I click the button.

Comment: maybe use `<input type="button" />` instead with `.click()` event instead of `.submit()`?